# Caml designer for SP2010 - connection probelm

Tags: sharepoint-addin, caml

I am new to SharePoint. I have a problem with `CamlDesigner2013`, it does not want to connect to my site (SP2010).

It complains about `the Credentials`!! I am using the administrator account, and still no change.

Any idea what is the problem ?

I did a small search on the internet and U2U tool is not working either.

Is there another Caml tools I can use ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is not related to the type of CAML Builder rather than the credential provided.

- Make sure the SharePoint 2010 is up to running.
- Make sure the credential provided is correct.

Regarding your question about other tools you can check

- [spcamlqueryhelper](http://spcamlqueryhelper.codeplex.com/)
- [SmartCamal Tool](https://sikorski-workshop.azurewebsites.net/Application/Details/smartcaml)

The features of new Smart CAML

- Browse and update SharePoint list items using CAML.
- Support for SharePoint 2010+ and SharePoint Online
- Build Caml query using designer
- Update list items
- View all hidden clist columns
- Caml designer will advice you how to build correct query